# php fatal error, require once

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

Hi guys working with Zend search lucene and im getting the following warning and error:

```
   Warning: require_once(Zend/Search/Lucene/Storage/File/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\Search\Lucene\Storage\Directory\Filesystem.php on line 349

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Search/Lucene/Storage/File/Filesystem.php' (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in G:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\Search\Lucene\Storage\Directory\Filesystem.php on line 349
```

i think its this line that is making it happen:

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create('LuceneData/');
```

can anyone give me some advice on what is going on? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your Zend Library to include path.

If your Zend Framework is in `G:\xampp\htdocs\includes\Zend`, then you have to include it so:

```
<?php
$path = 'G:\xampp\htdocs\includes\Zend';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Also you should give absolute path for Lucene data. For example:

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create('/var/searchindex/LuceneData/');
```

The folder `/var/searchindex/LuceneData/` should exist and be writable.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, how would i include the zend library? ive searched but ive come across alot of different answers